# Why should I hide my website index?

Tags: html, indexing

I've tried looking it up and am now coming back to here to see if I can get my question answered. Why should I make it so that others cannot view my indexes? Is there a security reason for this?

I'm just beginning in web development....so I definitely could use any help/info that you all can provide.

Comment: Do you want people looking at all the files you have in a folder?  If the answer is no, then hide them.  It's generally a good idea for security reasons.  The less access, the better.

Comment: What do you mean by 'indexes'? Do you mean `index.html` or `index.php`? They are generally referred to as 'Default document'. You can hide them from the url to make the url a little cleaner and more easy to remember.

Comment: @GolezTrol - He's referring to directory indexes which you can configure apache to either hide or show by default.

Comment: If using Apache, use `mod_rewrite` to hide index.html

Comment: @Axel, yeah I figured after I saw your comment. I'll leave mine just in case, but I think you are right. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often considered a security best practice to hide directory listings.  You may accidentally upload files to your docroot that you don't want to share to the world.  Without knowing the URL, nobody would be able to access them.  While this is a very thin layer of security, it can be helpful.

There are certainly times when you may want a directory listing, such as download directories.  It's up to you to decide what is useful to you.  If you don't need it, don't use it.  If you do, use it.